# Proxmox VM not loading after upgrading vm to debian 8 jessie

Tags: linux, debian, proxmox

I have a problem and I can't find how to solve it so if anybody can give me a hand I will be gratefull.

After upgrading one of my proxmox vm to debian 8 jessie all worked fine, but when I have restarted the vm doen't load.
I have connected through the VNC of Proxmox and shows this when booting and I can't type or do anything.

---

```
systemd 215 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVININT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR)

Detected virtualization 'openvz'.

Detected architecture 'x86-64'.

Welcome to Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)!

Sethostname to <srv4>.

Failed to enable kbrequest handling: Invalid argument

Cannot add dependency job for unit rpcbind.service, ignoring: Unit rpcbind.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Cannot add dependency job for unit display-manger.service, ignoring: Unit display-manager.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Assertion 'clock_gettime(clock_id, &ts) == 0' failed at ../srv/shared/time-util.c:33, function no(). Aborting.

Caught <ABRT>, dumped core as pid 53.

Freezing execution.
```

---

Anybody knows what it's happening?

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2):

now I know what has happened.

I installed a new virtual machine (openVZ containter) (CT) with debian 8 and had the same problem at start, I thought that the problem was with the upgrade but having the same problem with a new fresh debian 8 install I have search for new solutions.

The problem it's that I was running Proxmox 3.2 which uses a linux Kernel not compatible with Debian 8.
https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/debian-8.22043/

So be adviced, if you are using Proxmox 3.x don't upgrade your CT's to Debian 8 jessie or your machines will never restart.

Important, after the upgrade all works perfectly until you restart, I was working with Debian 8 for more than one month after the upgrade with any issues, until I needed to restart.

Best!

Comment: I think I got the same issue. What to do to fix the problem? Downgrade Debian? Restart proxmox?